# ¿Como habilitar un textbox en jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

lo que necesito es que un textbox este deshabilitado y se habilite hasta que escriba 4 números en un textbox anterior.
Los textbox son asp:Textbox.
La verdad no lo he intentado porque nose como, y se me ocurre que pueda ser con jquery o desde el behind code c#.
Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto yo usaría el evento **keyup**

[Documentación jQuery keyup() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp)

espero te sirva

```js
$("#txt1").keyup(function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  if (_this.val().length >= 4) {
    $('#txt2').removeAttr("disabled");
  }else{
    $('#txt2').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

```css
input[disabled] {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" id="txt1" placeholder="Escribe ...">
<input type="textbox" id="txt2" disabled>
```